# Android: no difference found between an apk file signed for release and for debug

Tags: android, release, apk

I have just built for release my first Android App. I signed it with a key using keytool.exe.

Then, I did the following. I uploaded to a website both files, the apk signed for release and the apk signed for debug.

Then, with my Android device I entered the website and clicked on the two file links. They both behaived equally. The files where downloaded in the same way. And I could install both by clicking on them once they were in the 'download' folder.

I expected some differences. For instance, the device automatically installing the release version when clicking directly from the website.

What are suposed to be the differences between a release and a debug apk file?

Thanks.

Comment: One difference is that Play Store won't accept an apk signed with a debug key.

Comment: Yes, but I am more focused on other issues. For instance, in my experiment I did not achieve what the Android website says: "When users browse to the download link from their Android-powered devices, the file is downloaded and Android system automatically starts installing it on the device."

Answer (score 2):

- All applications must be signed. The system will not install an application on an emulator or a device if it is not signed.
- To test and debug your application, the build tools sign your application
  with a special debug key that is created by the Android SDK build
  tools.
- When you are ready to release your application for end-users, you must sign it with a suitable private key. You cannot publish an application that is signed with the debug key generated by the SDK
  tools.
- You can use self-signed certificates to sign your applications. No certificate authority is needed.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Ali, apps must be signed and built as a Release version for the Google Play Store and for devices to allow installation.

On android device you can allow Unsigned packages, but this is not recommended unless testing your own.

The main difference between a debug and release would be the compile method and how it gets signed. This will not differ how a android device will access the APK.

If on the play store, the APK is pushed to your phone and installs. Linking or downloading a APK file from a website onto the device will only download the file, The user will still need to Open/Run/Install the application.